# Order results of LINQ expression by an Enum

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following model entity:

```
public class Itinerary 
{
    public int Id {get; set }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public EnumType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum EnumType
{
    Start,
    Intermediary,
    End
}
```

I would like to sort first based on the Enum (property named `Type`) then based on the DateTime (property named `Date`). I already tried the expression below but this is not ordered by `Type` first

```
var itineraries = t.Itineraries.OrderBy(x => x.Type).OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList();
```

How to order results of my LINQ expression, first by `Type` (order: Start, Intermediary, End) then by `Date` ?

The reason is because sometimes there are no dates defined then I need to sort by type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ThenBy to further sort:

```
var itineraries = t.Itineraries.OrderBy(x => x.Type).ThenBy(x => x.Date).ToList();
```